# Rails how to version the models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version

I have created rails application using rails 5 and ruby 2.3. 
 I want to add few changes in some model files and save it as new application. I want two run both applications in production as two similar applications. I know how to version the controller by using namespace but I didn't get solution for version rails models.

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying you want to run two copies of the application in production under different namespaces (e.g., /v1/ and /v2/), both sharing the same database?

There's no easy way, because it's not a good idea. Each time you change to one application, you'll have to remember to change both - and worse if you add more versions in the future.

If possible, you should share one codebase and put any versioning logic in the controller that accesses the model.  Your controller can inspect the route that was used to hit it (/v1/ or /v2/) and respond accordingly.

In order to share one database between two versions of your code, you'll need to ensure that any changes you make to the database schema are backwards- and forwards-compatible, meaning you can only add new tables or columns (never rename or remove).

If you don't need the two versions of your app to share the same database, you could give the new version its own copy of the database (`database: my_schema_v2` in `config/database.yml`).

Or you could give the v2 of your model its own table name:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "products_v2"
end
```

But again, that means products would not be shared between the old and new versions of your code.